# Problema com Background Html/Css

Tags: html, css

Criei um `id` no css com um background. Quando eu coloco a `div` no html o background fica beleza, mas quando eu coloco um `<form>`, a parte que ele ocupa fica branca.

[image: Como fica:]

Obs: quando coloco o texto em negrito também da no mesmo.

Como posso resolver isso?

[Aqui tem um exemplo no JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7r7b4/) e o meu código tá assim:

#### CSS

```css
#backgroundSlider{
   width: 100%;
   background: #000;
   height: 300px;
}
```

#### HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<html>
    <head><title>Página de Contato</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    </head>
<body>
<div id="site">
    <div id="barramenu">menu menu menu menu</div>
    <div id="backgroundSlider">
    slider
        <form>
            Nome: <input type="text" name="nome"/><br>
            Email: <input type="email" name="email"/><br>
            Mensagem: <input type="text" name="menssagem"/><br>
            <input class="button" type="submit" value="Enviar"/>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="backgroundInfo">
    Background info
    </div>
    <div id="rodape">rodape</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Felipe, bemvido ao Stackoverflow! Acho que a votação foi um bocado dura porque faltava muita informação. Agora a pergunta está com muito melhor aspecto! Para adicionar HTML basta usar espaçamento (4 espaços) ou usar `\``, por exemplo assim: `\`var foo;\``, teste isso no seu `<form>` que está escondido na pergunta. Já agora, pode criar um jsFiddle com este problema? Assim vai ter uma resposta certamente mais ráipda.

Comment: Tem alguma regra de css para o form? pode ser que o mesmo está com o background-color setado em branco, sendo assim quando tu coloca o form na página o fundo dele fica branco. Tem como montar um JSFiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Editado, e obrigado pelas dicas e paciência pessoal.

Comment: JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7r7b4/
O form tá sem formatação, tá como padrão mesmo.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Vendo o teu [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7r7b4/), o problema esta no CSS mesmo. Tu tens uma regra

```
*{
    background-color:   #FFF;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

Ai que está o problema, pois tu está setando para todos os elementos (operador *) uma cor de fundo branca, e é por isso que quando tu adiciona o form o fundo dele fica branco.

Comment: Se por Default a cor do fundo ja é branca.. por que criar uma regra assim?

Comment: Provavelmente estava testando alguma coisa, daí devo ter colocado o background branco.
Muito Obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Sem problemas! Até mais, bom desenvolvimento.

Comment: @okevinlira Branco não é cor default de fundo, de onde tirou isso? Esse é um grande engano, no meu browser por exemplo ficam horríveis os sites que partem dessa premissa. A cor de fundo depende do browser e do esquema de cores do OS.